# Oro Commerce Page Component

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I need to add js code that check customer added to form has a property or not, if yes do an action. for example in image below I want to check if the customer added to the form has company type or not, if yes then hide a specific part, I am new to OROcommerce and has no idea how to do it can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make the Symfony form, used for rendering, [dynamic](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data).

If it's the form type defined somewhere in a vendor folder, you'll need to define the above listeners in a [form type extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html).

Then, you need to handle that with the JavaScript page component:

- [example](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/IntegrationBundle/Resources/public/js/channel-view.js#L113)
- [documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/javascript/page-component/#dev-doc-frontend-page-component)

Comment: can you tell me how add js in twig file?

Comment: You have to register it in the Resources/config/jsmodules.yml file. https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/configuration/yaml/jsmodules/#reference-format-jsmodules